# java.util.NoSuchElementException in synchronized LinkedList

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, linked-list, synchronization

Following synchronized `Queue` is accessed by number of producers and consumers, it is synchronized but it is still giving `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when extracting element from queue. What is the matter with it and how to resolve it.

```
public class Que{

    private Queue queue = new LinkedList();

    public synchronized void enqueue(Runnable r) {
      queue.add(r);
      notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Object dequeue(){
        Object object = null;
        try{
            while(queue.isEmpty()){
                  wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        object = (Object)queue.remove();// This line is generating exception
        return object;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe an InterruptedException occured?

Comment: I take it `queue.add(r)` should be `queue.add(e)`?

Comment: aguibert you are right it was a typo error by me here but it is not in my real code

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and i have resolved it too.
InterruptedException has occured and the interrupted status need to be restored in the catch statement and also need to be return as follows.

```
public class Que{

    private Queue queue = new LinkedList();

    public synchronized void enqueue(Runnable e) {
      queue.add(e);
      notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Object dequeue(){
        Object object = null;
        try{
            while(queue.isEmpty()){
                  wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();//restore the status
           return ie;//return InterruptedException object 
        }
        object = (Object)queue.remove();// This line is generating exception
        return object;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems incredibly unlikely that returning the exception is the right choice there.

Comment: I wouldn't return an exception. You should only throw it.